# How to resolve Mongo PostSessionEndPipeline failed or Session Submit has failed error

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics, mongodb

Did anybody experience below issue? Recently I have been seeing below error messages in log files. I verified the Mongo connection and it seems to be working as expected and below seems to be happening couple of times in a day:

```
    4808 20:53:52 WARN  Session Submit has failed.
Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted 10.146.24.201:27017
Source: System
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(IPEndPoint remoteEP)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.Open()
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(BsonBuffer buffer, Int32 requestId)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Internal.MongoConnection.SendMessage(MongoRequestMessage message)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.CommandOperation`1.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase.ExecuteBatch(MongoConnection connection, Batch`1 batch, Int32 originalIndex)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.BulkUnmixedWriteOperationBase.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.UpdateOpcodeOperationEmulator.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.Operations.UpdateOpcodeOperation.Execute(MongoConnection connection)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollection.Update(IMongoQuery query, IMongoUpdate update, MongoUpdateOptions options)
   at Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateStore.UpdateAndReleaseItem(String application, String id, String lockCookie, SessionStateActions action, SessionStateStoreData sessionState)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.SharedSessionState.SharedSessionStateManager.SaveAndReleaseContact(Contact contact)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.ContactManager.SaveAndReleaseContact(Contact contact)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.SubmitSession.Process(CommitSessionPipelineArgs args)

4808 20:53:52 ERROR PostSessionEndPipeline failed.
Exception: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
Message: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted 10.146.24.201:27017
Source: System
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CommitSession.SubmitSession.Process(CommitSessionPipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.PostSessionEnd.CommitSession.Process(PostSessionEndArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Web.Application.RaiseSessionEndEvent(HttpApplication context)
```

Note: TCP IP port range is set to default which is 5000. We don't have any custom MaxUserPort set in registry and same with TCPTimedWaitDelay which isn't set.

Comment: what version of sitecore and mongo you have? I see same issue when mongo 3.0 was used

Comment: Sitecore.NET 8.1 (rev. 160519) / Mongo : 3.2.6

Answer (score 1):

You have these errors because you don't use the right version of Mongo.
For Sitecore 8.1 you should use Mongo 3.0

Please have a look on next link : https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/633863 
[image]